# Compare Ending Character to List

Tags: c#, regex, string, compare

I am trying to compare the last character of a string to a list of known values, and if any of the known values match the end char, set a flag.  I have figured out how to do it vs. one character, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it vs. a list.  Can anyone help?  Here is my code so far:

```
StringBuilder myGrade = new StringBuilder();

// then I pull some data, calculate some stuff, give a grade, build the string, etc.  The resulting text can vary, but the grade letter will always be last.

var goodGrades = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
string endStr = myGrade.ToString();
endStr = endStr.Substring(Math.Max(0, endStr.Length - 1));
if (endStr == "A")
     //do some stuff for passing grades
else
     //do some other stuff for failing grades
```

Again, this works perfectly for a single char...but how would I go about checking each item in the goodGrades list?  Is there a regex possibility?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What do you mean it works for a single char? Can you show us a use case for multiple chars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(goodGrades.Contains(endStr))
{
   //Do something.
}
```

Also, this works for chars as well. And if you are trying to just compare a single character, this is a better way of doing it.

```
//Create a list of chars instead of strings
List<char> goodGrades = new List<char>(){'A', 'B', 'C'};
//Get the last char of your string by index
char endChar = myGrade.ToString()[myGrade.Length - 1];

//See if char is contained in list of chars
if(goodGrades.Contains(endChar))
{
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm still learning, so I knew it had to be simple.  Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Check out my edit. Here is a better way of doing it for this case.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `List.Contains`

```
if (goodGrades.Contains(endStr)) { 
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm still learning, so I knew it had to be simple.  Muchas Gracias!

Comment: @The_Land_Of_Devils_SriLanka there is no `endChar` in the OP code

Answer (score 1):

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx)

```
if (goodGrades.Contains(endStr))
  do something
else
```